# How to combine linkable and non-linkable text in flex3?

Tags: flex3

I need to combine the text "Register your phone number" and the linkable text "Register Now". How do I do it?
   The result needs to look like Register your phone number Register Now

Answer (score 1):

Use htmlText property.

1.Setting htmlText at AS3.

```
linkable.htmlText = "Register your phone number <a href='http://www.adobe.com'>Register Now</a>";

<mx:Label id="linkable" selectable="true"/>
```

2.Setting htmlText at MXML.

```
<mx:Label id="linkable" selectable="true">
    <mx:htmlText>
        <![CDATA[Register your phone number <a href='http://www.adobe.com'>Register Now</a>]]>
    </mx:htmlText>
</mx:Label>
```

If you want to open the link in a new window, use linkHandler like below.

```
public function linkHandler(event:TextEvent):void {
    // Open the link in a new window.
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest(event.text), '_blank')
}

<mx:Label id="linkable" selectable="true" link="linkHandler(event)">
    <mx:htmlText>
        <![CDATA[Register your phone number <a href='event:http://www.adobe.com'>Register Now</a>]]>
    </mx:htmlText>
</mx:Label>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. If you want to do something fancy, though, you can use [character boundaries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837705/character-boundaries-of-text-field-based-on-parent) to create visible (or invisible) buttons. This is useful for touchscreen applications in my experience.